# Incompatible Compose runtime version

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I am trying to implement compose in multi module project and i am constantly getting following error:

```
androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin.IncompatibleComposeRuntimeVersionException: You are using an outdated version of Compose Runtime that is not compatible with the version of the Compose Compiler plugin you have installed. The compose compiler plugin you are using (version 1.0.3) expects a minimum runtime version of 1.0.0.  at androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin.VersionChecker.outdatedRuntimeWithUnknownVersionNumber(VersionChecker.kt:119)
```

I only have on version specified (1.0.3) for all Compose dependencies, i also tried adding compose compiler to root build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
      implementation "androidx.compose.compiler:compiler:1.0.3"
}
```

At the root file i also added configuration for compose:

```
 buildFeatures {
       compose true
 }
 composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion '1.0.3'
 }
 kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
 }
```

And then in module build.gradle i added compose dependencies (compose ui, material, ui toolign preview and uitooling), i also upgraded gradle to latest 7.0.2 and still same error poping, i checked gradle dependency tree no sign on 1.0.0 compiler anywhere, any idea what else i could try or what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Do you have direct depency on compose runtime? Or is it transitive from other libraries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so the issue was i had to include activity-compose dependency on root gradle, and with that it works normally (if i try to include it per module it does not work)

Answer (score 0):

implementation "androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.6.1"
Use it in app gradle.